SAS compare month to month when the dataset has monthly figures across columns
I have list of firms (gvkey) and years (fyear). Per each firm-year observation, I have monthly sales across columns (columns sale_1 through sale_12 for January sales to December sales). I'd like to compare sales every month (e.g., January to February, February to March and so on) and create 11 set of variables for each difference (e.g., diff_2=sale_2-sale_1 and so on). Is there array or do loop I can use to create these variables instead of writing diff_2 through diff_12?
I was thinking of creating proc sql to merge every month but that sounds even longer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you transpose to have one observation per firm-year-month,  you would only need to calculate one variable with the difference between months, easily done using the DIF function.

If you just want to compare SALES_1 to SALES_2 then that should be trivial.
data want;
  set have;
  diff2 = sale_2 - sale_1;
  diff3 = sale_3 - sale_2;
  ...
run;

You could make a couple of arrays and then use a DO loop, but it hardly seems worth it for only 11 new variables.

Array solution (SQL is not the right approach in SAS here)
data want;
set have;

array _sales(12) sale_1-sale_12;
array _diff(2:12) diff_2-diff_12;

do i=2 to 12;
   _diff(i) = _sales(i) - _sales(i-1);
end;

run;

